# Функция обращается ко всем элементам, а не к выбранному

Tags: jquery

Написал функцию, которая ищет input и присваивает css-свойство соседствующему с ним label. Функция вместо того, чтобы поочерёдно искать все инпуты и рядом стоящие label, берёт самый первый input, делит его ширину на 2.35 и присваивает всем label значение первого инпута.

```
$(function() {
    var input = $('.input-holder input');
    var width = input.width();
    var label = ('.input-holder input + label');
    label.css('left', width / 2.35);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="input-holder col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
    <input id="takeoff_place" class="place focus-input" type="text">
    <label for="takeoff_place" class="place-label">Пункт отправки</label>
    <i class="material-icons">flight_takeoff</i>
</div>
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: `var label = ('.input-holder input + label');`   разве не `var label = $('.input-holder input + label');` !

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var input = $('.input-holder input');
  var width = input.width();
  var label = $('.input-holder label');
  label.css({
    'left': width / 50,
    'color': 'red'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-holder col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <input id="takeoff_place" class="place focus-input" type="text">
  <label for="takeoff_place" class="place-label">Пункт отправки</label>
  <i class="material-icons">flight_takeoff</i>
</div>
```